# How can I give `def formfield_for_manytomany` an id of editable object

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

```
class Report(models.Model):
    precursor = models.ManyToManyField(Precursor)

class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        ops_area = Report.objects.get(id=???????).ops_area
        print id
        print ops_area
        if db_field.name == "r_precursor":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Precursor.objects.filter(ops_area=ops_area)
            print kwargs
        return super(ReportAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

How can I give `def formfield_for_manytomany` an id of editable object?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you're after the `Report` instance being edited by the `ReportAdmin`, try this:

```
class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_object(self, request, object_id):
        # Hook obj for use in formfield_for_manytomany
        self.obj = super(ReportAdmin, self).get_object(request, object_id)
        print "Got object:", self.obj
        return self.obj

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "r_precursor" and getattr(self, 'obj', None):
            kwargs["queryset"] = Precursor.objects.filter(
                ops_area=self.obj.ops_area)
        return super(ReportAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(
            db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: 'ReportAdmin' object has no attribute 'obj'

Comment: Sorry, that hook would only work in an Inline -- try the updated code (note I also added the `getattr` in the second method)

Comment: This does not work at all for me.  get_object is never called.  From what i can tell that method goes undocumented as well for the modeladmin.

Comment: It depends on where you are using it (and perhaps the version of Django). You can also try within the the `get_form` and `get_formset` methods. See my [pre-edited post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5216214/revisions) for a version which works for an inline.

Comment: DrMeers you are by definition `THE MAN`.  Got it working with the combination of your pre-edits and using get_form.  What a struggle this was.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DrMeers Is thr any way I can check if user is adding a new object or editing previous one in formfield_for_manytomany() method.I need to filter value on edit or new object add bases.So please help me how can I check this in formfield_for_manytomany() method.

Comment: It seems that `get_object` method had some change in new versions. So you have to use `def get_object(self, request, object_id, from_field=None)` instead.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with DrMeer's otherwise excellent answer is that the object will be cached inside the `ModelAdmin` instance and its lifetime will extend until next `get_object()` call. However, `get_object()` is not called when adding a new report, so the wrong, previous report `obj` will be present when you add a new report after changing an existing report.

A safer approach is to cache the report object in the **request**, so it has request scope:

```py
class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_object(self, request, object_id, from_field=None):
        obj = super().get_object(request, object_id, from_field=from_field)
        # Cache object for use in formfield_for_manytomany
        request.report_obj = obj
        return obj

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "r_precursor" and hasattr(request, 'report_obj'):
            kwargs["queryset"] = Precursor.objects.filter(
                ops_area=request.report_obj.ops_area)
        return super(ReportAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(
            db_field, request, **kwargs)
```