# How to create a repeating generic field on a Django model that does not render entries from other objects in the admin?

Tags: django, django-models, database-design, many-to-many

I'm fairly new to Django, but wondering how to get one seemingly obvious thing to work in my model definitions.

For a model "Product" I want to be able to add any number of links, so I made a more or less generic "Link" model with a display name field and a URL field. In Product I add this as `ManyToManyField` with the respective Link model.

This works like intended in the admin view in that I can add any number of links and do so inline. However, I only want the admin view to list existing links of *this* product, let the user delete them, and let the user add new ones. What I do not want is for the inline link field to display all other product’s links.

Am I confused with the Field Type or overall approach, or how can I get this to work? I was wondering if the [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) options is the way to do this, or if this is merely something you should do in the admin forms and not on model level?

*Edit: Code sample added below*

*Edit: Code sample updated with `formfield_for_manytomany`*

In `models.py`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    links = models.ManyToManyField('Link', related_name='links', default=None, blank=True, null=True)

class Link(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=256)
```

In `admin.py`:

```
class LinksInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Link

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [LinksInline]

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        kwargs["queryset"] = Link.objects.filter(font_id=self.object_id)
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Link)
admin.site.register(Product)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to filter the inline manytomanyfield's queryset by the product that you are adding/editing?

Comment: @SachinKukreja If that is the way to do this most commonly in Django, then yes. My Link model is just a generic piece of data I want repeated, maybe even in several other models. I am interested in making those fields have same structure, but I am not interested in actually cross-populating the objects across models that use the Link model.

Comment: Please post some relevant code showing what you have already done.

Comment: @SachinKukreja I've update the question with the essential parts.

Comment: I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226760/filter-manytomany-box-in-django-admin) question which seems to do something like I am looking for, but as per my edited code the `formfield_for_manytomany` function does not seem to be having any effect. I tried placing log statements in that method, but they never get logged.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5216214/5312750)

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong but somehow the my code inside `formfield_for_manytomany` never seems to get run. I've added debug traces before, and in the method, and the ones in the method never show. I suspect otherwise this would be the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was very obvious, the filtering in the `ProductAdmin` never came into effect, because it was not registered:

```
admin.site.register(Link)
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Edit: Now that I've further attempted to get this working I notice that the entire question is unnecessary based on the fact that out of the box the inline behavior is just what I wanted — only I thought it did not work due to the missing ProductAdmin register. Simply registering the Inline and defining the the Link model with a ForeignKey to the Product will take care of this. Following the link in the comments, I did get the non-inline select box to filter as described, using the stored object to filter the manytomany result against — alas, it is not needed.